# Which is valid syntax for route of ads/ad_locations editor?

Tags: laravel

In my Laravel 8 app I want to make route of ads/ad_locations editor

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth'], 'prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.'], function () {
    ...
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'ads'], function ($router) {
        ...
        Route::resource(
            '/{ad_id}/ad_locations',
            AdLocationController::class
        )->name('admin.ads.ad_locations');
```

But I got error clearing routes :

```
$ php artisan route:cache

   ArgumentCountError 

  Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Routing\PendingResourceRegistration::name(), 1 passed in /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/AdsBackend8/routes/web.php on line 112 and exactly 2 expected

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/PendingResourceRegistration.php:110
    106▕      * @param  string  $method
    107▕      * @param  string  $name
    108▕      * @return \Illuminate\Routing\PendingResourceRegistration
    109▕      */
  ➜ 110▕     public function name($method, $name)
    111▕     {
    112▕         $this->options['names'][$method] = $name;
    113▕ 
    114▕         return $this;

  1   routes/web.php:112
      Illuminate\Routing\PendingResourceRegistration::name()

      +3 vendor frames 
  5   routes/web.php:119
      Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic()
```

Which syntax is valid and how to ref in in blade file ?

**MODIFIED BLOCK:**

I modified in routes/web.php :

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth'], 'prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.'], function () {
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'ads'], function ($router) {

        Route::resource('/{ad_id}/ad_locations', AdLocationController::class, [
            'names' => [
                'index' => 'admin.ads.ad_locations.index',
                'store' => 'admin.ads.ad_locations.store',
                'edit' => 'admin.ads.ad_locations.edit',
            ]
        ]);
```

and run command with success :

```
php artisan route:cache
```

But in blade file using it :

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('admin.ads.ad_locations.edit',[$ad_id, $nextAdLocation['id']]) }}">
    {!! showAppIcon('edit') !!} Edit
</a>
```

I got error :

```
(Symfony\\Component\\Routing\\Exception\\RouteNotFoundException(code: 0): Route [admin.ads.ad_locations.edit] not defined. at /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/AdsBackend8/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php:429)
[stacktrace]
```

Which way is correct ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function **name()** doesn't work with **route::resource**, because it's a collection of routes, it should be used with individual routes like:

```
Route::get('user/create', [UserController::class, 'create'])->name('user.create');
```

You can either supply a "names" array as the third parameter (options) parameter to the resource route, like:

```
Route::resource('user', UserController::class, [
    'names' => [
        'index' => 'admin.ads.ad_locations.index',
        'store' => 'admin.ads.ad_locations.store',
        // etc...
    ]
]);
```

or, you can use with **as** keyword, like the one you have used in your route:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth'], 'prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.ads.ad_locations.'], function () {
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'ads'], function ($router) {
        Route::resource('/{ad_id}/ad_locations', AdLocationController::class);
    });
});
```

In the above snippet, I have used your complete route "admin.ads.ad_locations" name in **"as"** attribute's value. But, this last one will be treated as prefix for every single route like this:

```
admin.ads.ad_locations.{ad_id}.store
admin.ads.ad_locations.{ad_id}.create
...
```

You can also, use function **names()** like below:

```
Route::resource('/{ad_id}/ad_locations', PhotoController::class)->names([
    'create' => 'admin.ads.ad_locations.build'
    'show' => 'admin.ads.ad_locations.view'
]);
```

**Answer For Rectified Section of the Question:**

Because you are using "as" attribute in your route as well, the route names generated for you will be:

```
admin.admin.ads.ad_locations.store
admin.admin.ads.ad_locations.create
admin.admin.ads.ad_locations.create
```

You can either remove the **as** attribute from your route, like:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth'], 'prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'ads'], function ($router) {
        Route::resource('/{ad_id}/ad_locations', AdLocationController::class, [
            'names' => [
                'index' => 'admin.ads.ad_locations.index',
                'store' => 'admin.ads.ad_locations.store',
                'edit' => 'admin.ads.ad_locations.edit',
            ]
        ]);
    });
});
```

or, you can avoid using **"admin."** in your routes names, like:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth'], 'prefix' => 'admin', 'as' => 'admin.'], function () {
    Route::group(['prefix' => 'ads'], function ($router) {
        Route::resource('/{ad_id}/ad_locations', AdLocationController::class, [
            'names' => [
                'index' => 'ads.ad_locations.index',
                'store' => 'ads.ad_locations.store',
                'edit' => 'ads.ad_locations.edit',
            ]
        ]);
    });
});
```

Comment: Pls look at MODIFIED BLOCK

Comment: I added extra portion to the answer.